# java, anonymous Inner class issue

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

Let's assume I need a specific application-wide actionListener. For example:

```
public class TestAnonymousInnerClass {
    private ActionListener closeAction = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This code compiles and works fine, but can I say that I have used an **anonymous inner class** to instantiate this `closeAction` field?

UPD:
I am reading the book *SG Ganesh, Tushar Sharma - Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7 Programmer Exams 1Z0-804 and 1Z0-805 (The Expert's Voice in Java) - 2013* And here is the confusing illustration: [image] As follows it is not possible to have anonymous and 'non-local' class.
But my class seems to be of that kind because it is not in context of method and still anonymous.

Comment: I don't really get it, what do you mean by *can I say*? In this case, closeAction is instantiated by an abstract inner class, yes.

Comment: @Merguez: Anonymous, not abstract. The class created is concrete.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, wrong wording.

Comment: The author would have to define what he means with "Local"/"Non-local". If by local he only means "defined inside a method", then he's wrong.

Comment: Your example is in fact "local" because field initializer expressions become part of the constructor(s) when the class is compiled.  You could say that the local/non-local distinction is between classes that are defined in code that is executed and classes that are defined directly as members of another class (in your case the _instance_ of the anonymous class is a member of the container, but the class itself isn't).

Comment: An anonymous class is _always_ an inner class ([JLS §15.9.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5))

Comment: Hmm I've been playing with that and now I'm even more confused as to what the meaning of all those types is: http://ideone.com/sJRKqN

Comment: In fact, according to the JLS, an anonymous class is NEVER a "local class". JLS 14.3: "A local class is a nested class that is not a member of any class and that has a name." So the author must have some other meaning of "local".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You have created a annonymous inner implementation class of `ActionListener` interface. And instantiate it and assigned to `closeAction` variable

In short we can say that an anonymous class is an inner class that does not have a name at all. And whose instance is being created at the time of its creation. Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) for more details.

Comment: Or rather, an anonymous class implementing the ActionListener interface.

Comment: Mb I am a bit not clear. I have read that `inner classes` can't be anonymous. Is it an inner class?

Comment: Only inner classes can be anonymous, actually.

Comment: Updated question. Can you check please?